# How to add new line every nth position in list?

Tags: java, list

im trying to do as the title says but im currently getting the wrong output, what am i doing wrong in this piece of code?

```
public void AAAAA(String thetext, int numb)
  {
    List<String> items = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(thetext.split(" "))); //split string to individual characters
    int len = items.size(); //get size of string
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){ // loop through list
        if(j % width == 0){  
            items.add(numb, "\n");
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(items);
  }

}
```

text example: "hello my name is bob i like to pet cute fat dogs"

expected output if `numb` is 3;

`hello my name`

`is bob i`

`like to pet`

`cute fat dogs`

Comment: hint number 1: when you insert a line the value of `items.size()` changes

Comment: As you append to the list, the length also changes. Consider adding to a different list instead of the original list.

Comment: Providing current output and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: @BallisticBlaze sure, i'll update the answer now.

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: @BallisticBlaze - not really, the error is obvious

Comment: [Duplicate account?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52302210/1553851)

Comment: @mckuok sure thing thanks

Comment: If you are trying to wrap text, I recommend Apache's WordUtil class. It has a method for wrapping long strings and does a great job at it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's a matter of convention. All questions should provide code, an explaination and if applicable, current output and expected output.

Comment: @BallisticBlaze thanks for the Apache's WordUtil hint i'll check it out, as for my code, whats wrong with it?

Comment: *whats wrong with it?* - do you bother to read the comments people has taken the time to post?

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of using modula and appending to a new list

```
String thetext = "hello my name is bob i like to pet cute fat dogs";
int splitOn = 3;

String arr [] = thetext.split(" ");
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {

    buf.append(arr[x]).append(" ");
    if ((x + 1) % splitOn == 0) {
        newList.add(buf.toString());
        newList.add(" ");
        buf = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
newList.add(buf.toString());

for (String line : newList) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print a newline for every 3 words (for numb = 3), you can modify your method to print out the contents of the list and use your modulo logic there. There's no need to add or modify the list.